# when drop a database using Spring JPA EntityManager native query, runs into SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I try to drop a database using EntityManager native query but it throws `SQLGrammarException`

Code snippet:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("DROP DATABASE :schema").setParameter("schema", test_schema).executeUpdate();
```

It Throws:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test_schema'' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar:8.0.21]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
```

Comment: What is the value of `test_schema`? Are there quotes in it?

Comment: test_schema is String variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more tries, I think It's not supported in JPQL.
So I used JDBC to do that.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JDBCExample {
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "root";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Open a connection
      try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      ) {             
         String sql = "DROP DATABASE database_name";
         stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
         System.out.println("Database dropped successfully...");      
      } catch (SQLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } 
   }
}
```